# How to automatically gather data from Microsoft Outlook Calendar to Word?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I want to know if I can automatically gather data from Microsoft Outlook Calendar to Word file.

I am working for two coworkers and currently manually write down their meeting information on Word from Outlook Calendar. Apparently, this is very inefficient, and I want to know if I can automate this process. I would very much appreciate advice.

Comment: Why can't they just access the calendar directly?

Comment: @DavidPostill What do you exactly mean? I am responsible for writing their meeting information on word..

Comment: Instead of creating a word document give them access to the calendar.

Comment: [3 Quick Methods to Export Your Outlook Calendar to a Word Document - Data Recovery Blog](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/3-quick-methods-export-outlook-calendar-word-document/)

Comment: @DavidPostill It's their own calender so they of course have access. But I am responsible for writing them and delivering it to someone else.

Comment: @JunJang Do you mean you want all existing and future meetings to be automatically copied to a Word document? Maybe some add-in can do this. Or, you can switch to List view, highlight the events, right-click and Copy, then paste to a Word document.